# Dell Latitude E6410 blank screen

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bios, blank-screen

**The culprit:**  Dell Latitude E6410 with Intel HD graphics and Bios A13 (latest)

**The OS:**  Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit

**The issue:**  Installing graphics drivers causes the internal LCD to go blank.  External displays work great as the main display, but nothing is shown on the internal LCD when inside of Windows with the display driver installed.

**Notes of interest:**  The bios screen shows fine on the machine, and the bios states that it has an Intel HD graphics card (originally thought maybe it had the nVidia NVS but was installing the wrong driver)  Without a driver installed (Using standard vga driver)  the internal monitor is fine.

**What I have tried:**

1. My standard method of building laptops - MDT 2012 + WDS - works great on every other laptop
2. Fresh build of Windows 7 from the DVD.  Installed only the network card driver and rebooted, works, then installed the video driver and rebooted = blank screen
3. Updating with drivers from Windows Update
4. Updating with drivers from Dell directly
5. Updated the bios (was A03, went to A09, then A13 for good measure)
6. Attempted to follow the instructions listed [here](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3519/p/19423743/20079493.aspx) and had the
   drivers error out during install.
7. *EDIT* Also tried all of the FN+F8 combinations (duplicate, extend, single monitor, etc) with no luck.

**Hopes and dreams:** Someone out there has run into this error before, and has documented a proven way of fixing it.

Comment: I guess you get the same behavior (blank screen) if you boot the laptop with no external monitor connected?

Comment: Correct.  Also edited to include other steps.

Comment: Are there any settings in the BIOs relating to switching display adapters?

Comment: @Bigbio2002:  Sadly no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

1. Boot to safe mode with networking
2. Removed the display driver with the checkbox to delete the files
3. Restarted
4. Downloaded the QM57/QS57 Intel GMA HD Drivers (multidriver download # R296701)
5. Install drivers
6. Reboot

Now I feel silly.

Comment: I know this is an older thread, but wanted to throw a "thanks" your way using the GMA driver from dell worked great. I did a fresh install of windows and everything worked fine(generic video driver) then I did Microsoft Windows updated that's when my screen went black. ANYWAY, saved me a bunch of time.

Answer (score 1):

I am having Dell Latitude E6410 with NVIDIA NVS 3100M graphics.
I had the same issue, no display after wake up. So I had to restart the notebook every time.
So I checked the NVIDIA web site and downloaded the latest compatible drive and installed. All ok now.

Comment: Exact same hardware here. Exact same result. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either you have a whack driver in your share OR Plug and Play is grabbing the wrong driver.

I highly recomend storing all your drivers in MDT in the following order:

Name of OS \ Name of Architecture \ Name of Make* \ Name of Model*

- As listed in MSInfo32

For Example Win7\x64\Lenovo\3167AS3

Then create a task sequence variable

`DriverGroup001` that has

`Windows 7\x64\Lenovo\%Model%`

set just prior to inject drivers and set the selection profile to nothing.

This "total control" model of driver management in MDT will make your deployments much, much smoother.